# skaffold dev does not start my react native application

Tags: react-native, docker, kubernetes, skaffold

Before I wrapped up my client folder inside of docker, kubernetes and skaffold i created an expo project and was able to run it using npm start and then pressed i to run the ios simulator. However, since everything is wrapped up inside of docker, kubernetes, and skaffol and when i run skaffold dev its not starting my application properly.

here is my Dockerfile
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"];